# How to add values to keys in a dictionary for keys found in a file? Python

Tags: python, list, file, python-3.x, dictionary

So I have a csv file, from which I have to find the average price for all products grouped by category.  I managed to put all lines from the file into a list. 
Now I'm trying this:

```
FILE_NAME = 'catalog_sample.csv'
full_catalog = []

with open(FILE_NAME, encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:            
        one_record = line.split(',')
        full_catalog.append(one_record)

category_dict = {}
prices = []

for i in full_catalog:
    if str(i[-2]) not in category_dict:
        category_name = str(i[-2])
        category_dict[category_name] = float(i[-1])
    else:
        prices.append(float(i[-1]))
```

So far I'm getting a dictionary with all the categories from the file as keys, but the value is the price from the first occurrence of the key in the file:

```
'Men': 163.99
'Women': 543.99
```

It seems that "else" is not working as I'm expecting (adding values to the keys). Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: A bunch of stuff, but none of them worked, and I decided not to share them.

Comment: how do you add elements to a python `list`, do you know that?

Comment: Yes, with append.  I've tried iteration through the catalog and then prices. append,  but then it just adds all prices for each key. The problem is I don't know how to search in the file for the keys and then return the price corresponding to that key.

Comment: I think it would be best to show what `full_catalog` looks like, the way you are indexing is confusing.

Comment: What I meant was if you print out `full_catalog` what does it look like?

Comment: I've added the full code :)

Comment: Oh, it's a list of lists, that contains strings.

Comment: I've gathered that, but it helps to know how many items those nested lists contain. And if there are any duplicates. Just a sample is fine. Or even how a line of the file looks like.

Comment: Here's what a line in the file looks like:
'109128', '2COLOUR LOGO 3P', 'BLACK/MEDGREHEA', 'TRAINING', 'SOCKS', 'Unisex', '846.99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating your dictionary while going through the file, instead of adding them to a list and going back through it to construct the dictionary.

```
category_dict = {}
full_catalog = []

with open(FILE_NAME, encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        item = line.split(',')
        # Unpack the last 2 items from list
        category = item[-2].strip()
        price = float(item[-1])

        # Try get the list of prices for the category
        # If there is no key matching category in dict
        # Then return an empty list
        prices = category_dict.get(category, [])
        # Append the price to the list
        prices.append(price)

        # Set the list as the value for the category
        # If there was no key then a key is created
        # The value is the list with the new price
        category_dict[category] = prices
        full_catalog.append(item)
```

Edit: Fixed to match provided line format.
`full_catalog` has been included if you still require the whole list